# Stopping Post Build events on project when building directly from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, build, post-build-event

I have a project which has some post build events that do some copying around for other projects. I unfortunately cannot change that, and have been asked to write a build script for use on a CI server.

Problem is that the post build steps run off the debug/release bin folders and I compile through the build script to a different folder. So one solution would be to let the project build as is, and then manually copy all files from the bin folders to the output folder I am using. However that feels like a bit of a hack, so I was wondering if there is a way for an MSBuild task to tell the solution it is building to ignore PostBuild events, I believe you could set a property PostBuildEvent='' but it didnt seem to stop them from happening...

Here is an example of the build script target:

```
<Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Clean;">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SourceDirectory)\SomeSolution.sln" 
            Properties="Configuration=Release; OutputPath=$(CompilationDirectory); PostBuildEvent=''" />
</Target>
```

Anyone had to do anything similar before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable all PostBuildEvents, set the CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets to C:\PostBuild.config (or whatever you name the file) and have PostBuild.config to be:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="PostBuildEvent"/>
</Project>
```

Add /p:CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets="C:\PostBuild.config" to your msbuild command line

Or update your MsBuild task properties:

```
<MsBuild Projects="$(ProjectTobuild)" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration);Platform=$(Platform);CustomAfterMicrosoftCommonTargets='C:\PostBuild.config'" Targets="Build"/>
```

Comment: Sorry if I am being a bit simple but can you elaborate? are you saying add a command line argument? as if thats the case I cannot do that, as the CI server runs the build script directly without the command line.

Comment: If you are using TFS CI server you can add additional msbuild parameters on Process tab

Comment: Am using CC.net at the moment, will give what you say a try but it feels nastier than copying from the bin files into the other folder, but if it works I guess you get the answer

Answer (score -1):

To disable PostBuildEvents at project level for MSBuild, simply put these codes inside .csproj:

```
 <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent Condition="'$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'false' Or '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true'"></PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
 </Target>
```